# What is Stored in Stateless JSON Web Tokens

Tags: javascript, security, authentication, cookies, jwt

I have been reading up on JWT recently, and feel I have a pretty decent grasp of how they are made and how the could be used for authentication.

If I understand correctly, a challenge with stateful applications occur when I need several web services (APIs), one for each type of device using the app (web, mobile, etc.). Then, the web services must somehow synchronize the session states, which is hard.

Instead, we store state client-side (preferably in cookies) within encrypted and signed JWTs.

Have I understood it correctly so far?

Then, my main question: What exactly is stored in the JWT, for let's say an online store? Does it completely replace all user info stored in a database? So, profile information, images, shopping cart, saved content (articles, repos, etc. if applicable), and more. Is all this, and all other imaginable content differing from one user to the next, saved inside the JWT?

In conclusion, I am trying to get at what is meant by stateless in JWT use cases? Do we store all user info in the token?

Comment: I had almost the same questions as you couple of days ago. This article (http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/) was very helpful for me to understand how JWT works and why it's not recommended to use it for sessions.

Comment: @juliobetta That's really useful, it kind of eliminates the issue. I still wonder what would be stored in such a session though, and why anyone would store everything in a JWT in a cookie. It is limited to 4kb (and web storage is not a secure option).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [..] when I need several web services (APIs), one for each type of device using the app (web, mobile, etc.).

I would argue that it's bad architecture to separate your server backend by the type of client. Ideally the backend will offer the exact same API to web clients and mobile clients (and any other clients). Otherwise you have a huge duplication and overhead for every supported feature.

So instead, let's just concentrate generically on the case where you have *several servers*. Any serious large scale web site, think Amazon.com, has way more than a single server serving their web site. They have individual server instances coming online automatically as demand increases and dropping back offline as traffic ebbs. Load balancers direct traffic to individual servers as necessary.

In that kind of scenario, especially with a shopping site, you have several ways to handle state then, each of which has certain pros and cons:

1. Use sticky sessions, which means web servers are stateful and store session information, and the load balancer is aware of the used cookies and will direct traffic from the same client to the same server so only one server needs to hold on to the session info. This makes the server implementation relatively simple, but has certain drawbacks in operation:

   - The load balancer needs to be able to handle sticky sessions.
   - The server needs to stay online while the client exists, otherwise the session information is discarded.
   - If the client moves geographically to another load balancer, they may get disconnected from their session.
2. Use a shared session storage backend, so each server essentially shares the same information. That negates the drawbacks from using sticky sessions, but obviously re-introduces the bottleneck of a single shared resource and impacts scalability. That can be mitigated to some extent by using good caching strategies, but writing to shared storage still requires an enormous backend.
3. Keep everything stateless and handle as much as possible on the client itself. The client remembers its own history and/or basket contents. All the server needs to do is provide the product information, which is non-client specific and therefore extremely scalable. Of course, when it comes time to checkout or do other client-specific things, the server will need to do client-specific actions and use a session of some sort or another, but that is just a fraction of the traffic compared to casual browsing and much less of a problem.

   In this kind of scenario, JWTs serve to carry information which needs to be validated, like *who a user is,* i.e. authentication. For authentication purposes, you can either:

   1. Have the client authenticate themselves with every request, i.e. send their username and password with every request. That is obviously a bad idea, since you don't want to send the password back and forth constantly. It would also require a query to a central database on the backend each and every time, which undermines scalability again.
   2. Give the user a token of some sort which authenticates them. The drawback here is that is requires a shared token store, see #2 above.

   JWTs let you have it both ways: the user essentially claims on every request that they're *user X* (without sending their password), and because the JWT is **signed** by the server, it allows the server to actually trust that claim. Each server can verify the signature independently, and hence trust the claim independently on each request, and thus remain stateless and also not require any sort of shared storage.

   A drawback of storing information in JWTs is that they only exist on one client, so any information you store there ceases to exist once the user moves to another client or clears cookies; so synchronising a shopping basket between devices for a user account is not possible with just JWTs alone.

In practice, you'll probably use at least two, probably all three approaches together. You'll have *some* shared storage somewhere to store account information (including the shopping basket), but you reduce the need to contact that storage as much as possible by *also* caching that data in sticky sessions and/or JWTs. Stateless authentication via JWTs is something of a no-brainer. For everything else, you decide on the right tradeoff between imparting load on a shared storage, how up-to-date any shared/cached state will be, and the end user experience.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write up. The article by @joepie91 in the initial comments above states that there is no reason not just to use session id in cookies + session body in database (like expression-session + connect-mongo) for everything. He seems to argue pretty well for all the security concerns. When it comes to multiple servers, there isn't really an issue right? AWS and other providers will allow one web service running across several servers?

Comment: Also, quickly, in your stateless case: Will ALL user related data be stored in the JWT? Profile image, contact details, wish lists, and more, chat, support communication, etc. etc.? That sounds impossible in one token, due to size.

Comment: Well, that is scenario 2 above, the shared session backend. The problem with that is that each and every request will hit that backend to validate the session information then, which can be thousands and thousands of requests per second for large scale operations. Running a database that can handle that load is… not trivial. That's where alternatives like JWTs that don't necessitate that database hit come in. If for 80% of casual web site hits you don't need a lot of information and can just use what you can store in a JWT, that reduces your load by 80%.

Comment: So, *you* decide what makes sense to store in a JWT for your service. No, you probably don't want to make it a huge payload, just enough to provide a frontend web server with enough information to quickly render a response without causing much backend load. Yes, that means the design of the page itself and the information you display on it need to be well considered so the server *can* render it quickly.

Comment: Again, you don't even need to cover *all* possible pages on your site. On a shopping site, 80% of traffic is probably product lists and product detail pages. On those pages you don't typically need any user specific information, apart from a "Hello Magnus" in the top corner. *That* can easily be stored in a JWT. For the other 20% of pages where you do need more information, it's okay to hit the database backend; you've already made 80% of your site super fast with JWTs.

Comment: (Sorry, this was posted before your above comments). Just so you don't have to search through, the crypto article says (using Redis as example):

If you run on multiple servers: A dedicated server running Redis just for session storage.

The above is your option (2) I believe. The article states that pretty much no-one needs that kind of scalability. It is not really a bottle neck as such, unless you are Reddit size. At that point you could easily make some of it stateless as you say.

Thoughts?

Comment: Yeah, *you* probably don't need it, that's right. You can probably run off a single shared PHP & MySQL server. Just stop thinking about it then. … But, that kind of tiny site you could probably implement as a "serverless" site (e.g. AWS Lambda), with tiny stateless instances, and if you don't get a lot of traffic you're running it virtually for free instead of paying for a 24/7 server. And if you happen to become really popular, you're already scaling well.

Comment: I'm not saying JWTs are a silver bullet. I'm explicitly contrasting three approaches and am saying that each has their pros and cons, and that you need to choose wisely. A wisely chosen balance can drastically reduce costs, increase scalability and improve performance. Where you set your priorities is up to you.

Comment: Thanks again. One quick question: Online shopping sites will often have a profile section, with lots of specific info relating to the user, including profile picture, support sessions (chat/emails/tickets), and lots more. Is that considered session data, i.e. stored in JWT in a purely stateless architecture?

Comment: No, there's little reason to store that kind of stuff in a session-like storage. Again, that would be part of the "other 20%" of pages which don't need to be blindingly fast, because they're not the pages most users spend most of their time.